# Search and Replace to Add Carriage Returns

Tags: paw-app

I'm calling a REST end point that is unfortunately very windows reliant and required the body of the return to have '\r\n' instead of the default '\n'.  Is there any hooks in PAW that could allow me to write a search and replace before sending a request?

Thanks

Comment: What body do you have? JSON, XML, form url-encoded? There are some options, nothing perfect, but we can hack something depending on the body itself.

Comment: The body is currently a Multipart, but it would be a valid path to switch over to just use a Text body if that made it easier to apply a hook for the given issue.

Comment: Is there anyway for an extension to do this?

Comment: Yes, that would be possible! If you take this as an example https://github.com/luckymarmot/Paw-Base64ToHexDynamicValue you would easily be able to make a search-and-replace feature to change \n to \r\n ...